# get the centroid row index from k-means clustering using sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Hy all,

I have a panda DataFrame from which, i would like to cluster all rows and get the row index of each cluster centroid . I am using sklearn and this is what i have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
Y = pd.DataFrame(kmeans.fit_predict(X.as_matrix()),columns=['cluster ID'] )
Z =pd.DataFrame(kmeans.cluster_centers_[Y['cluster ID']])
result = pd.concat([X , Y, Z], axis=1)  
pd.DataFrame(result)
```

is there any way to get the index of the closest row to centroid

thx

Comment: You can get cluster centers by using `kmeans.cluster_centers_`. Then find distance from all elements in that cluster to get the one with lowest distance.

Answer (score 0):

Thx. This code work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5))
model= KMeans(n_clusters=3)
clusassign = model.fit_predict(X.as_matrix())
min_dist = np.min(cdist(X.as_matrix(), model.cluster_centers_, 'euclidean'), axis=1)
Y = pd.DataFrame(min_dist, index=X.index, columns=['Center_euclidean_dist'])
Z = pd.DataFrame(clusassign, index=X.index, columns=['cluster_ID'])
PAP = pd.concat([Y,Z], axis=1)
grouped = PAP.groupby(['cluster_ID'])
grouped.idxmin()
```

Comment: You can use this:`np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(X_std - kmp.cluster_centers_[0], axis=1))`